# nginx location pattern match not working

Tags: nginx, configuration

I am trying to change the nginx configuration so that all the URLs which contain styles are stripped in such a way that only the part of the URL after and including the 'styles' is sent to a downstream app.

The request with URL "http://def.testing.com/abc/styles/fonts/Avenir-Roman/font.css" matches the first pattern but I am expecting it to match the second pattern because the second pattern has reg-ex in it.

Could someone please explain to me what is going on here?

```
location /abc/ {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
}

location /abc.*/styles/ {
    rewrite ^/abc.*/(styles.*) /$1 break;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
}

URL:

http://10.10.10.10/abc/styles/fonts/Avenir-Roman/font.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to add the tilde character in your regex?

```
location ~ ^/abc.*/styles/ {
    rewrite ^/abc.*/(styles.*) /$1 break;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
}
```